# Undefined index: entity_type_id while installing data in Magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I have upgraded my Magento-1.9 Module to Magento 2.1 while upgrading the Extension I am getting the following Exception:

Installing data...

```
[Exception]
  Notice: Undefined index: entity_type_id in D:\wamp64\www\..\vendor\m
  agento\module-eav\Setup\EavSetup.php on line 1065



setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]
```

Can somebody let me what could be the issue with entity_type_id?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please show the code of your setup script, this will help finding the issue without having to guess. Also, obligatory **one does not simply upgrade Magento 1 to Magento 2** (you were probably using a code converting tool, which helps to get started but cannot do all the work for you)

Answer (score 0):

Please show your code so I can find the problem [entity_type_id] mean primary key of your table you can change it with your table primary key.I think this file should have problem
The file :-Api\Data['your_interface_file'];

Also remove cache and re-index your code once.

You should also check your InstallSchema.php file Here is the example:-

```
 public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{  
    $installer = $setup;    

    $installer->startSetup();

    /**
     * Create table 'dedicated_employee'
     */
    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('dedicated_employee')
    )->addColumn(
        'entity_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Employee ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'e_name',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Employee Name'
    )->addColumn(
        'salary',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        10,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Employee Salary'
    )->addColumn(
        'profile',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Employee Image'
    )->addColumn(
        'is_popup',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
        'Show Popup'
    )->addColumn(
        'is_active',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '1'],
        'Is Employee Active'
    )->addColumn(
        'creation_time',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
        'Block Creation Time'
    )->addColumn(
        'update_time',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
        'Block Modification Time'
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for InstallData.php

```
namespace Solvingmagento\AffiliateProduct\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //associate these attributes with new product type
        $fieldList = [
            'type',
            'attribute_group_id',
            'affiliate',
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
        ];

        // make these attributes applicable to new product type
        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
                ',',
                $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
            );
            if (!in_array(\Solvingmagento\AffiliateProduct\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_AFFILIATE, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = \Solvingmagento\AffiliateProduct\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_AFFILIATE;
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```